# Minimize HTTP requests made to my server when using LocationManager

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

In the code below, I'm using LocationManager to get the user's current zipCode and then I make an HTTP request to my own server to get some data based on the user's zipCode. My issue is that my code below makes an HTTP request everytime `locationManager` is called, usually three times per call. Ideally I would like to make the HTTP request only once the last placemark is found.

How can I minimize the HTTP requests made to my own server?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)-> Void in
        if error != nil {
            //AlertView to show the ERROR message
        }
        if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            var zipCode = placemark.postalCode ?? ""
            makeHTTPRequest(zipCode) // this is called 3 times
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        }else{
            print("No placemarks found.")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that there are probably multiple calls to `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` stacked up by the time you do `self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`. To solve that:

- Define a global variable `var didFindZipCode: Bool = false`.
- Add `guard didFindZipCode == false else { return }` at the beginning of the if block in which you check for number of placemarks.
- Set `didFindZipCode = true` right after the guard statement.

Just remember to set `didFindZipCode` to `false` whenever you want to start updating the location again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `CLGeocoder` method returns asynchronously and by the time it returns a value, your location manager has already fired multiple times. Therefore, simply stop updating locations after the location manager's first call and then do your async work.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let location = locations.last else {
        return
    }

    // handle async work
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            // alert with error
        } else if let placemarks = placemarks,
            placemarks.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks[0]
            var zipCode = placemark.postalCode ?? ""
            makeHTTPRequest(zipCode)
        } else {
            print("No placemarks found.")
        }

    })

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() // stop updating

}
```

By the way, it's also good practice to chain your `if-else` statements. If you lead with an `if`, you should almost always follow it with an `else`, instead of following it with a new `if` block.

Comment: For some reason with your method, it was still making two HTTP requests. I ended up using a boolean property. I wish this would work since I think it is cleaner. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then just add the boolean test to this code but do not do what you were originally doing and toggling the location manager inside the async return. Separate those two tasks.

Comment: I left the code as I had it but added a boolean property as suggested by `nebuler`,. For some reason trying to `stopUpdatingLocation` before `CLGeocoder` doesn't do what I want.